# Problem displaying query data on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am having problems with the my visualforce page displaying the data from my SOQL query.

This is my controller:

```
public with sharing class fetchCaseCallsController {
private Id accountId;
public fetchCaseCallsController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    accountId = sc.getId();
}

public Task[] getTasks() {
    if (accountId != null) {
        return [
                select Id, Subject
                from Task
                where WhatId in (select Id from Case where AccountId = :accountId)
                and Type = 'Call'
                ];
    } else {
        return new Task[] {};
    }


   }
}
```

Basically in the controller I am querying all calls that were made against a case for a specific account.

My VF page looks as follows:

```
       <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="fetchCaseCallsController">

  <h1>Logged calls against cases</h1>
  <table>
  <apex:repeat value="{!tasks}" var="act">
    <tr>
      <td>This is the subject {!act.Subject}</td>
    </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
  </table>

</apex:page>
```

I don't really understand why nothing is displayed on my page?
Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 get methods defined for the caseCalls list.

One as part of the `{get;set;}` on line 4 and another in the `getCaseCalls()` method.

The page is probably returning the result of the `get;` on line 4. But this `caseCalls` variable is never set.

Remove line 4 (and line 8 in which you initialize the empty list) and it will work.

The alternative is to remove the `getCaseCalls()` method and fill the `caseCalls` list in the `fetchCaseCallsController` method (instead of just creating an empty list there).

Comment: I have now edited my code (see above), but I still can't see anything in my VF page?

Comment: Did you check the debug logs to see whether the accountId is set and whether anything is returned in the SOQL query?

Comment: for some reason it does not fetch any rows, which is strange... can you see anything wrong with my query?

Comment: I just simplified my query and it does then fetch rows, so there must be something wrong with my SOQL statement. Basically I want the SOQL statement to fetch all the calls that were made against a case that is linked to a specific account. Tks

Comment: The query syntax isn't wrong (e.g. it returns data in my org). So it must be either the user authorizations (the user viewing the page can't see the tasks) or the filter on Type. Also check if the Account is actually filled in on the Cases that you want to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no `Type` field on `Task` Object. If you have add a new custom field, change it into `Type__c`, then it should be works.

And instead of using repeat apex:repeat. I recommend you to use [apex:pageBlockTable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_iteration_components.htm), because it's the official way to working with table in Visualforce.